# "transferred over network" size larger than resource size

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using XMLHttpRequest to read the json file and find that "transferred over network" is significantly larger than the resource size.[image]

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "resources.json", true);
```

While others have resource size equal to or larger than "transferred over network". What happened to it? Should I be worried about this?

Comment: For such _small_ sizes, there is also significant HTTP [header] overhead. This overhead is not part of the resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transfered is the total amount of bytes traveled in both directions, while `resource size` is the size of received response body.

A HTTP request is composite of url, request headers, request body, response headers and response body.

See a sample message of a HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13

say=Hi&to=Mom
```

Note that the content length header is only `13 bytes` (only the `say=Hi&to=Mom` size),while this entire HTTP message contains `111 bytes`.

For more details see the message format section at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 5):

"Transferred" is the sum of the bytes for the total **sent and received** data in the displayed requests.

"Resource size" is the sum of the bytes for the received data, that's why they don't match.

Consider this example:

[image]

See how the Resources matches with the sum of received bytes for each request.

[image]

[image]